# Flexslider JS Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I believe this question has been asked multiple times and I have researched many other articles but I'm afraid I'm at a complete impasse...

I am trying to make a very basic flexslider but it simply does not seem to want to work for me.  The images appear as lists, so the HTML and the image links would seem to be Ok.  This leads me to believe I have missed something in the JS.

Would anybody be able to advise me?

Many Thanks in advance.
Ryan

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Place somewhere in the <head> of your document -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<!-- Place in the <head>, after the three links -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src="../lachantongeimg/group.jpg" alt=""/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="../lachantongeimg/howtojoin.jpg" alt=""/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="../lachantongeimg/playmusic.jpg" alt=""/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your photos appear like a list, must be the CSS file. Make sure the file exist or fix your path.

The only difference that I found with the official documentation is the option to animate:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

here there is a basic example working exactly as you have:

https://jsbin.com/jicodadace/2/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Hi Jose, thanks for your response.  I'll take a look at this and let you know my findings.

Comment: You were right about {animation: "slide"}  Also, the two links were missing from the <head>.